# jQuery animation stuttering when using CSS transform property

Tags: jquery, html, css

Everything almost works as intended except that the animation inside the `main-content` div stutters when I add the `transform` properties to center the the `main-content` div. It doesn't stutter when I leave all the transform properties out.

CSS:

```
.main-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
}
```

Code for the animation inside the `main-content` div

```
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.welcome').fadeIn({queue: false, duration: 600});
    $('.welcome').animate({top: "0px"}, 'slow');
  }, 700);
```

Any solutions for this issue?

Thanks

Comment: jQuery animation is extremely slow compared to CSS animation. You better use animation in a class definition and simply add or remove the class through jQuery.